# Multiple 'and' operators in Ansible 'when' condition

Tags: ansible, logical-operators, ansible-2.x

This is the code that I am trying to run

```yaml
- name: Read and Register Contents of .bash_profile
  shell: grep -E 'AB_AG_HOME|AB_AG_LOCAL_ROOT|AB_AG_LOCAL_DIR|AB_AG_CONFIG_DIR|AB_AG_LOG_DIR' /home/username/.bash_profile
  register: output

- debug:
  msg: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"

- name: Append AG environment variables in .bash_profile
shell: cat /home/{{ admin_user }}/tmp_bash.profile >> /home/{{ admin_user }}/.bash_profile
  when: "'AB_AG_HOME' and 'AB_AG_LOCAL_ROOT' and 'AB_AG_LOCAL_DIR' and 'AB_AG_CONFIG_DIR' and 'AB_AG_LOG_DIR' not in item"
with_items: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"

- name: Delete the temporary tmp_bash.profile"
  file:
    path: /home/{{ abinitio_admin_user }}/tmp_bash.profile
    state: absent
```

when I run this code, all the values are repeated 4 times.

Is there anything that is missing?

Answer (score 0):

By looping over the `stdout_lines` via

```yaml
with_items: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"`
```

the condition

```yaml
when: "'AB_AG_HOME' and 'AB_AG_LOCAL_ROOT' and 'AB_AG_LOCAL_DIR' and 'AB_AG_CONFIG_DIR' and 'AB_AG_LOG_DIR' not in item"
```

would only be `true` if all strings are in one line (`item`) together.

You may have a look into the following minimal example

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    result:
      stdout_lines:
        - "A1"
        - "A2"
        - "A3"
        - "A4"
        - "A5"

  tasks:

  - name: Debug one-line conditional
    debug:
      msg: "Not in stdout_lines"
    when: "'A1' and 'A2' and 'A3' and 'A4' and 'A5' not in result.stdout_lines"
```

Whereby the first given example get `skipped` because of the condition, the second example

```yaml
  - name: Debug loop conditional
    debug:
      msg: "Not in {{ result.stdout_lines[ansible_loop.index0] }}"
    when: "'A1' and 'A2' and 'A3' and 'A4' and 'A5' not in item"
    loop: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: true
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Debug loop conditional] ******
ok: [localhost] => (item=A1) =>
  msg: Not in A1
ok: [localhost] => (item=A2) =>
  msg: Not in A2
ok: [localhost] => (item=A3) =>
  msg: Not in A3
ok: [localhost] => (item=A4) =>
  msg: Not in A4
```

For further debugging you could also use the [`assert` module – Asserts given expressions are true](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html).